# Getting Segmentation Fault in C++, but why?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation fault in this code but i cant figure out why. I know a segmentation fault happens when a pointer is NULL, or when it points to a random memory address.

```
 q = p;
        while(q -> link != NULL){
            q = q -> link;
        }
        t = new data;
        t -> city = cityName;
        t -> latitude = lat;
        t -> longitude = lon;
        q -> link = t;
```

This is the error am actually getting in console:

```
line 33: 2219 Segmentation fault    sh "${SHFILE}"
```

Comment: @Carlos: why remove all that code ? As I understand it from the answer you accepted, some of it *was* relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `else` clause in `Database::add`, you do not set `t->link = NULL`, so it is uninitialized.

You should add a constructor for `data` that initializes its members, or use the value-initializing `new` to ensure that everything is initialized correctly:

```
t = new data(); // note the parentheses
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that it's because when you're adding a new node to the end of the list:

```
else{
    q = p;
    while(q -> link != NULL){
        q = q -> link;
    }
    t = new data;
    t -> city = cityName;
    t -> latitude = lat;
    t -> longitude = lon;
    q -> link = t;
}
```

you're not setting `t->link = NULL;`.

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting Database::data::link to `NULL` in `Database::add`:

```
    t = new data;
    t -> city = cityName;
    t -> latitude = lat;
    t -> longitude = lon;
    t -> link = NULL;
```

*EDIT*: 
I would add a constructor for `Database::data` to initialize the various members.  Something like:

```
class Database {
    struct data {
        data(): latitude(0.0), longitude(0.0), link(NULL) {}
        ...
    };
    ...
 };
```

Then you do not have uninitialized memory to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Compile with -g as an argument to g++

Then from command line "gdb (binary name)"

inside gdb, "run" and it will execute until the fault

type "bt" to see a stack trace

Comment: sorry for not spoonfeeding you what you needed. i'll remember not to answer your questions in the future

Comment: What tells you he's the one who downvoted you? (No, it wasn't me. ;))

Comment: I downvoted because A. The user appears to be a beginner and probably is not aware of a "stack trace". B. The user is not running from a commandline and probably has no experience with gdb. C. Nothing says the user has GDB installed. D. You spent no time looking at the code and answering the question, you simply put in a response that is canned, etc.

Comment: I still think giving OP a tip to use a debugger is more valuable than pointing out the flaw itself. Teach them to fish, etc. Figuring out how to use gdb is an exercise to the reader

Comment: Maybe that's what you think, but I'm looking at the question and it says, "What's wrong with this code". Your answer does not answer that question, and you assume the user knows too much given what he's posted. For example, the user is using netbeans. You don't even know he knows what g++ is much less gdb. Therefore I downvoted.

Comment: as a sidenote, this is clearly homework so i don't feel bad giving generic advice.

Comment: If you want to give generic advice, that's fine, but generic advice belongs as an aside to an actual answer to the OP's specific question, or in a comment.

Comment: +1: Debuggers are especially useful when dealing with memory-related issues -> good answer.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other issues but here's one:

```
else{
    q = p;
    while(q -> link != NULL){
        q = q -> link;
    }
    t = new data;
    t -> city = cityName;
    t -> latitude = lat;
    t -> longitude = lon;
    q -> link = t;
}
```

You never set `t->link` to null and therefore it's filled with junk.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign t's link to NULL:

```
else{
    q = p;
    while(q -> link != NULL){
        q = q -> link;
    }
    t = new data;
    t -> city = cityName;
    t -> latitude = lat;
    t -> longitude = lon;
    t -> link = NULL; // add this
    q -> link = t;
}
```

Comment: Heh, we all answered at the same time.